# Ubuntu equivalent of the Cisco Anyconnect vpn client

Tags: software-recommendation, vpn

Is there a Debian/Ubuntu equivalent package of the Cisco Anyconnect vpn client? If so then how do I install and use it?

Answer (score 7):

There is a package called `openconnect` which does the job. To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install openconnect vpnc
```

and to run it, so that you can access the restricted network (eg through your browser):

```
sudo openconnect vpn.hostname.com
```

and enter the username and password when prompted on the command line. Or to input them automatically all in one go:

```
echo 'the!!password' | sudo openconnect -u 'the!!username' --passwd-on-stdin vpn.hostname.com
```

To send the script to the background so that you can continue using the command line:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>

then

```
bg
```

(for background).

Comment: There are also OpenConnect plugins for Network Manager that may make it easier to setup.